# Write a WP7 program which installs ringtones?

Tags: windows-phone-7

One thing I really miss on my windows phone 7 is the ability to set a custom ringtone.

Is it possible to write a program which installs (custom) ringtones for selection in the phone?

Or is there any way to buy/sell ringtones (create a package with a ringtone and sell it on app hub, for example)?

In the [German documentation for ringtones](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/de-de/howto/wp7/start/ringtones-and-sounds.aspx) it says ringtones can be bought and installed from marketplace.
In the [English version](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/start/ringtones-and-sounds.aspx) of this page it says custom ringtones can not be installed.

Translation error, or is the german version of the phone different? If there really is a method to buy ringtones, it must be possible to package them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because your app is sandboxed and you have only access to IsolatedStorage and some other stuff via Lunchers and Choosers.

Comment: Funny. The german documentation says it is possible to buy ringtones from marketplace, so it should be possible to package and sell them. I checked the english version of the docs, and lo and behold: no word of buying ringtones. Translation error I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The next Windows Phone update called "Mango" announced at MIX11 last week will have custom ringtones and as I understood during the Keynote you can create apps that allow users to set a ringtone from your app.